# Sending data from the Activity to the fragment through the listener

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface

I have an Activity in which there is a ViewPager, in this ViewPager has some fragments. And I need to send data to fragment when it is displayed on the screen. So I want to implement an interface in the Activity that will send data to the fragment.

```
public interface SetDataToFragment {
        void getData(List<FinanceOperationModel> aModels);
    }

public class FinanceMonitoringActivity extends ApiActivity2 implements FinanceMonitoringView
        , FinanceMonitoringFragment.SaveDataInterface {

    private SetDataToFragment mInterface;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_finance_monitoring);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        mInterface= (SetDataToFragment) this;
...
```

And then there is an error:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.akbars.bankok.screens.financeMonitoring.FinanceMonitoringActivity cannot be cast to com.akbars.bankok.screens.financeMonitoring.SetDataToFragment

**How do I properly initiate an interface in an Activity to use data in a fragment?**

Comment: FinanceMonitoringActivity doesn't implement SetDataToFragment

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send the data to the view pager fragment you can do that from the viewPager adapter class or if you want to do from the activity implement the interface in activity and call that from the fragment to return the needed data.

Answer (score 0):

Create one interface in your Activity and pass your data via the interface to the fragment. Implement that interface in your fragment to get data.

For example

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DataFromActivityToFragment dataFromActivityToFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentA fr = new FragmentA();
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        dataFromActivityToFragment = (DataFromActivityToFragment) fr;
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                dataFromActivityToFragment.sendData("Hi");
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(r, 5000);


    }

    public interface DataFromActivityToFragment {
        void sendData(String data);
    }
}
```

**FragmentA.class**

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements MainActivity.DataFromActivityToFragment {

    TextView text;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, null);
        text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_text);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void sendData(String data) {
        if(data != null)
        text.setText(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Activity `FinanceMonitoringActivity` does not implement `SetDataToFragment` so you can not cast it to `SetDataToFragment`

Implement `SetDataToFragment` in `FinanceMonitoringActivity`